# Using ChemicalData to make molecule graphics

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, curated-data, chemistry

$\require{mhchem}$I would like to take the acetone $\cf{((CH3)2CO)}$ and chloroform $\cf{(HCCl_3)}$ molecules that *Mathematica*'s chemical data provides, and plot them together.  I want to show how chloroform can hydrogen bond to acetone.  Right now I have them plotted on top of each other :/

```
Show[ChemicalData["Chloroform", "MoleculePlot"], 
 ChemicalData["Acetone", "MoleculePlot"]]
```

[image: acetone and chloroform]

Comment: ...I don't think *Mathematica* is the best software to use for this. Why not use a dedicated 3D chemical drawing program?

Comment: @J.M. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e6/MasteringTheArtOfFrenchCooking1edCover.jpg

Comment: If you examine the `FullForm` of the molecular plots, you may come up with a one-off solution.  Some assembly may be required.

Comment: Are there any free 3D chemical drawing programs?

Comment: Somewhat related (for post-processing): [Can a LatticeData image be displayed in a space filled fashion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18789/245).

Comment: "Are there any free 3D chemical drawing programs?" - you could have used the fantastic search engine to answer that, but [here's one](http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/), and [here's another](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick way of showing how the two structures can be positioned relative to each other in a single `Graphics3D` is as follows:

```
With[{rMax = 500},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[
   {First@ChemicalData["Acetone", "MoleculePlot"], 
    GeometricTransformation[
     First@ChemicalData["Chloroform", "MoleculePlot"], 
     Composition[
      TranslationTransform[{displacementX, displacementY, 
        displacementZ}], 
      RotationTransform[
       rotationAngle, {Cos[axisAzimuth] Sin[axisPolar], 
        Sin[axisAzimuth] Sin[axisPolar], Cos[axisPolar]}]]]},
   PlotRange -> {{-rMax, rMax}, {-rMax, rMax}, {-rMax, rMax}}
   ],
  {{displacementX, 0}, -rMax, rMax}, {{displacementY, 0}, -rMax, 
   rMax}, {{displacementZ, 0}, -rMax, rMax}, {rotationAngle, 0, 
   2 Pi},
  {axisPolar, 0, 2 Pi}, {axisAzimuth, 0, 2 Pi}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: manipulate]

The `Manipulate` is just to let you do some manual re-positioning. You can eventually get better results by doing pre-calculated shifts and rotations based on the exact locations of the atoms. But I'm focusing here on the basic ingredients. For the display, this involves mainly the use of `First` to extract the contents of the `Graphics3D` of the molecule, then the translation and rotation using `GeometricTransformation` with a `Composition` of the former two operations.

The variable `rMax` sets the plot range and the maximum displacement of the chloroform molecule relative to the acetone.

Comment: +1 Very nice! Now this is the first step to do genetic manipulation completely inside Mma :D

Comment: wow, excellent work.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a less impressive take on the question.

```
positionsA = 
   ChemicalData["Acetone", "AtomPositions"] /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x + 400, y + 400, z + 400};
positionsC = ChemicalData["Chloroform", "AtomPositions"];
{atomsA, atomsC} = {ChemicalData["Acetone", "VertexTypes"], 
                     ChemicalData["Chloroform", "VertexTypes"]};
{colorsA, colorsC} = {Map[ColorData["Atoms", #] &, atomsA], 
                       Map[ColorData["Atoms", #] &, atomsC]};
{radiiA, radiiC} = {Map[ElementData[#, "VanDerWaalsRadius"] &, atomsA], 
                     Map[ElementData[#, "VanDerWaalsRadius"] &, atomsC]};
{molA, molC} = {Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 40], 
                MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, #3]} &, {colorsA, positionsA, radiiA}]}], 
                 Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 40], 
                MapThread[{#1, Sphere[#2, #3]} &, {colorsC, positionsC, radiiC}]}]};

Show[molA, molC, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]