# Modifying imported 3D file

Tags: graphics3d, export, import, chemistry

Since I am visualizing my work using Mathematica, I import some 3D models of molecules to my notebook. So, the question is, is there any way to modify somehow that imported models inside Mathematica to, for example, label bonds' length? Currently I use .mol2 format, but maybe some others formats provide that ability? Or can Mathematica process that models to `Graphics3D`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we import the model:

```
mol = First@Import["ExampleData/abacavir.mol2"]
```

It will look like this:

[image: mol1]

After that, we can confirm that *Mathematica* has converted the model into a `Graphics3D` object by typing `mol//InputForm`. This answers one of your questions.

As an example of how to edit this model in *Mathematica*, I will create the object you mentioned, one where the bond lengths are shown.

First we need to know where to put the labels so in order to do that we calculate the midpoints of each bond. To do this we will use information provided by the MOL2 file, `EdgeRules` and `VertexCoordinates`. The first tells us which atoms link to which and the latter tells us the position of all the atoms. The positions are given in picometer, and the relative distances between atoms will be the bond length in that unit.

```
edgeRules = 
  First@Import["ExampleData/abacavir.mol2", "EdgeRules"] /. 
   Rule -> List;
vertexCoordinates = 
  MapIndexed[First@#2 -> # &, 
   First@Import["ExampleData/abacavir.mol2", "VertexCoordinates"]];
paired = edgeRules /. vertexCoordinates;
```

The above sets up a list `paired` in which each element is a list of two coordinates, these coordinates correspond to atoms that are bound to each other. This visualization confirms that we can now find the midpoints:

```
midpoints = #[[2]] - (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 & /@ paired;
Graphics3D[{Join[{Green, Sphere[midpoints, 20]}, List @@ mol]}]
```

[image: mol2]

The final step is to write the bond lengths on the corresponding midpoints, which is easy thanks to the `paired` list.

```
lengths = Norm[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] & /@ paired;
labels = Text[#[[2]], #[[1]], Background -> Black] & /@ 
   Transpose@{midpoints, lengths};
Graphics3D[Join[{Green, labels}, List @@ mol]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

C. E. does a fine job in answering the question of how to annotate a molecular model in *Mathematica*, but fails to address the 800-pound gorilla in the room, which is that **Mathematica doesn't import multiple bonds**.  Taking a look at the [wiki page for Abacavir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacavir), we see that there are a number of double bonds that don't show up when using `Import`.

[image: abacavir]

Fortunately, the information is there, but we essentially have to build our molecule ourselves.

```
First@Import["ExampleData/abacavir.mol2", "EdgeTypes"]
(* {"Aromatic", "Aromatic", "Aromatic", "Aromatic", "Aromatic", "Single", ... *)
```

I have been working on a molecular viewer (it's [still in progress](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26720/building-a-molecule-viewer-aesthetic-rotations)) but it has some of the features that the OP is looking for.  I apologize in advance for long code.  First, I import the molecule information:

```
{atomtypes, atomcoords, bonds, bondtypes} = First@Import["ExampleData/abacavir.mol2",
    #] & /@ {"VertexTypes", "VertexCoordinates", "EdgeRules", "EdgeTypes"};
bondtypes[[{2,3,4,5,21,22}]]="Single";
```

The 2nd command is to address the fact that I haven't yet coded aromatic bonds (they by default show up as double bonds instead of a bond/dashed bond).

The code to build a molecule, including options for highlighting and labeling:

```
Options[makemolecule] = {hilight -> {}, labels -> {}, 
   labeloffset -> {1, 1, 1}};
makemolecule::badcoord = "2D coordinates suspected, use \
PadRight[#,3]&/@coords"; 
makemolecule[atoms_, coords_, bonds_, bondtypes_, OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{colors, sizes, hb, b1, b2},
  colors = {
    "H" -> RGBColor[0.65, 0.7, 0.7],
    "C" -> RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 0.4],
    "N" -> RGBColor[0.29, 0.44, 0.89],
    "O" -> RGBColor[0.8, 0.2, 0.2],
    "F" -> RGBColor[0.58, 0.86, 0.41]
    };
  sizes = {
    "C" -> 34, "H" -> 24, "O" -> 31, "N" -> 32, "F" -> 30};
  hb = Mean@coords[[#]] & /@ ({#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ bonds);
  b1 = coords[[bonds[[All, 1]]]];
  b2 = coords[[bonds[[All, 2]]]];
  If[(Dimensions@coords)[[2]] != 3,
   Message[makemolecule::badcoord]
   ];
  GraphicsGroup[{EdgeForm[None],
    (* Make the atoms *)
    GraphicsComplex[coords, {
      MapThread[{#1 /. colors, Sphere[#2, #1 /. sizes]} &, {atoms, 
        Range[Length[atoms]]}]}],
    (* Make the bonds *)
    GraphicsComplex[Join[b1, hb], {
      Riffle[atoms[[bonds[[All, 1]]]] /. colors,
       Table[GeometricTransformation[
           Cylinder[{#, Length@b1 + #}, 10],
           TranslationTransform[ k Normalize[hb[[#]]\[Cross]b1[[#]]]]
           ], {k, 
           bondtypes[[#]] /. {"Single" -> {0}, "Double" -> {-15, 15}, 
             "Aromatic" -> {-15, 15}, "Triple" -> {-15, 0, 15}}}] & /@
         Range[Length@b1]
       ]
      }],
    GraphicsComplex[Join[b2, hb], {
      Riffle[atoms[[bonds[[All, 2]]]] /. colors,
       Table[GeometricTransformation[
           Cylinder[{#, Length@b2 + #}, 10],
           TranslationTransform[k Normalize[hb[[#]]\[Cross]b2[[#]]]]
           ], {k, 
           bondtypes[[#]] /. {"Single" -> {0}, "Double" -> {-15, 15}, 
             "Aromatic" -> {-15, 15}, "Triple" -> {-15, 0, 15}}}] & /@ 
        Range[Length@b2]
       ]
      }],

    (* Hilight atoms *)
    If[Length@OptionValue[hilight] > 0,
     GraphicsComplex[
      coords, {Opacity[0.6], Green, 
       Sphere[#, 35] & /@ OptionValue[hilight]}]],
    (* Add labels *)
    If[Length@OptionValue[labels] == Length@atoms,
     GraphicsComplex[
      coords, {Black, 
       MapThread[
        Text[#1, OptionValue[labeloffset] + #2, 
          BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
            Orange}] &, {OptionValue[labels], coords}]}]]

    }
   ]];
```

(Yes, only 5 elements in my periodic table at the moment...)  I can then view a molecule using:

```
molview[molecule_] := Graphics3D[{
   Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 100], molecule
   },
  Boxed -> False,
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  SphericalRegion -> True, Background -> Black]
```

Putting all that together, I get:

```
molview@makemolecule[atomtypes, atomcoords, bonds, bondtypes]
```

[image: abacavir with dbl bonds]

And the `makemolecule` function can accept some rudimentary highlighting and labeling options

```
molview@makemolecule[atomtypes, atomcoords, bonds, bondtypes, 
    hilight -> {1, 3, 5, 7,     9}, labels -> atomtypes, labeloffset -> {50, 50, 0}]
```

[image]

Now I have to take a closer look at [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731)'s answer to see if there's anything I can incorporate into my function.  Hope this is useful.