# Rotate manually 3D graphics when (auto)playing

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, animation

Is there a possibility in *Mathematica* to allow for manual rotation of 3D graphics when (auto)playing either using `Manipulate` or `ListAnimate`? (When one plays a sequence of 3D graphics using `ListAnimate` it is not possible to rotate manually the graph as when it is static.)

Comment: I hope it is not possible to do what you ask. I think any attempt to  allow what you ask for would produce nightmarish thread conflict between the thread updating the graphics under animation control and the thread updating the graphics under mouse control. I would expect the 2nd of these two threads to be blocked while animation is running.

Comment: @m_goldberg Instead of blocking, it might be done with time division multiplex technics?

Comment: @Silvia. Sound good but do you think _Mathematica_'s front-end supports that?

Comment: @m_goldberg I doubt so. But maybe we can simulate one with nested `Dynamic`s?

Comment: @Silvia. If what you suggest can be made to work, I predict the performance will be unacceptably bad.

Comment: @m_goldberg I made one along that way and the performance is indeed bad -- but not *unacceptable* IMO. Will try a 3D graphics case before shape an answer.

Comment: @Silvia. Go for it. I am intensely interested in seeing what you come up with.

Comment: @m_goldberg At a second thought, I believe I already (partially) did it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39519/17) with a much simpler way :)

Comment: [LiveGraphics3D](http://www.vis.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/documentation.html) allowed interaction with 3D graphics while an animation was running. Sadly, it has yet to catch up with current *Mathematica* versions.

Comment: @Silvia I use this one http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: @belisariusisforth Thanks! I found [this one](https://screentogif.codeplex.com) (and plan to study its code :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As there seem no easy way to hack `ListAnimate` or `Manipulate`, we'll try to construct a custom "animator", using the method I mentioned in [an earlier post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39519/17) with some generalization.

First we generate all frames of the animation:

```
frameLst =
        Module[{range},
            range = Range[0, 2, .1];
            Plot3D[
                   Im[ArcSin[(.5 Abs[# - 1])^3 (x + I y)^4 Exp[2 # π I]]],
                   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
                   (* quality too high will crash the Dynamic system: *)
                   PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 1,
                   ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Red},
                   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, 4 {-1, 1}}, 
                   SphericalRegion -> True
            ] & /@ range
        ];
```

Then we make it move automatically using a [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html):

```
With[{n = Length@frameLst, opts = glst[[1, 2]]},
    DynamicModule[
        { k,
          frameDataLst = Cases[frameLst, _GraphicsComplex, ∞]
        },
        DynamicWrapper[
           Graphics3D[
              Dynamic[frameDataLst[[k]]],
              opts
           ],
           k = Clock[{1, n, 1}, 3]
        ]
    ]
]
```

[image: rotatable auto-animation]

The key point of the trick is keeping a persistent `Graphics3D` object across frames. So instead of writing `Dynamic[Graphics3D[...]]`, we should use `Graphics3D[{...,Dynamic[...],...}, options]` to prevent the `Graphics3DBox` being destroyed at each frame, which will leave it no time to respond to the dragging operations from mouse.

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks :)