# Dataset on a sphere

Tags: visualization

Is it possible do a similar graphic (and animation) with *Mathematica*? (Please see the example of dataset on a sphere in [this link](http://sos.noaa.gov/Datasets/dataset.php?id=643)). To see the rotating sphere, click on the "View the Interactive Sphere" button.

Comment: To see the rotating sphere, click on: View the Interactive Sphere button.

Comment: Might be doable with `EarthquakeData[]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is just to illustrate some ways utilizing resources from this site.

In the following I have just plotted earthquakes from December 2015 to earley 2016 with magnitude between 2.5 and 4 (for no particular reason).

**Make Sphere**

Code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60430/1997):

```
img = With[{\[CapitalDelta] = 30}, 
  Row[Table[
    GeoGraphics[GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], 
     GeoRange -> {{-90, 
        90}, {\[Lambda], \[Lambda] + \[CapitalDelta]}}, 
     GeoProjection -> {"Equirectangular", 
       "Centering" -> {0, \[Lambda] + \[CapitalDelta]/2}}, 
     ImageSize -> Small, 
     GeoGridLines -> Quantity[10, "AngularDegrees"], 
     GeoGridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.4, 0.5]], {\[Lambda], -180, 
     180 - \[CapitalDelta], \[CapitalDelta]}]]]
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, \[Pi]}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), Boxed -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[img], Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, 
  RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  ViewPoint -> {-2.026774, 2.07922, 1.73753418}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

**Autorotate**

Code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39401/1997):

```
autoRotate[gr_Graphics3D, rate_: 5] := 
 DynamicModule[{vp, va, vv, vc}, {vp, va, vv, vc} = 
   gr~AbsoluteOptions~#~OptionValue~# &@{ViewPoint, ViewAngle, 
     ViewVertical, ViewCenter};
  Overlay[{Show[gr, SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Dynamic[vp],
      ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
     ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc]], 
    Show[gr, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
     SphericalRegion -> True, 
     ViewPoint -> 
      Dynamic[RotationMatrix[Clock[2 \[Pi], rate], vv].vp], 
     ViewAngle -> Dynamic[va], ViewVertical -> Dynamic[vv], 
     ViewCenter -> Dynamic[vc]]}, All, 1]]
```

**Data**
The data is irrelevant as my point is to illustrate feasibility and one way.

```
ds = {DateList@#1, f[#2, #3], #4} & @@@ dat[[All, {1, 2, 3, 5}]];
ds = Reverse[ds];
gth = GatherBy[ds, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]} &];
vp[a_, b_, c_] := 
{Text[Style[DateString[a, {"MonthName", "  ", "Year"}],White, 20], 
{0,0,1.5}],Red, PointSize[rs[c]], Point[b]};
gra = vp @@@ # & /@ gth;
anim = Show[Graphics3D[#], ppl] & /@ gra;
```

The data is grouped into earthquake locations and magnitudes by month and `gra` just makes a point at location with size scaled by magnitude.

An example visualization:

```
Manipulate[
 autoRotate[anim[[month]], period],
 {month, Range[13]}, {period, {5, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I will try the code. Thank you.