# ImplicitRegion gives arbitrary boundaries

Tags: plotting, random, regions

This question uses Mathematica 10.2.0.0.

`equation1` is the major unbounded region I would like to generate:

```
s = 0.36109;
t = 1*(1 - s);
equation1 = 1.505 < (1 - s)*8*(Sin[2*x]*Sin[z]*Cos[y] + Sin[2*y]*Sin[x]*Cos[z] +
    Sin[2*z]*Sin[y]*Cos[x]) - s*4*(Cos[2*x]*Cos[2*y] + Cos[2*y]*Cos[2*z] + 
    Cos[2*z]*Cos[2*x]) - t;
```

Now I generate an implicit region, I am bounding this by {x,y,z} as well as by two {1,-1,2} planes

```
region1 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 <= x - y + 2*z <= 7,
     {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}];
```

`region1` will be used to define a region to randomly assign {x,y,z} points

```
pts1 = RandomPoint[region1, 10^4];

ListPointPlot3D[pts1, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

You can see from the plot that the z bounds are arbitrarily chosen, more problematic, the x- and y-bounds will change with z, e.g. if z is unbounded the x-bounds will be from ~-5 to 5Pi
[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the meantime, while `RandomPoint[]` is being fixed, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57938)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in `RandomPoint`, as can  be seen by plotting both `region1` and `region2`, the latter defined by

```
region2 = ImplicitRegion[6 <= x - y + 2*z <= 7, 
    {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}];
```

Then

```
pts2 = RandomPoint[region2, 10^4];
ListPointPlot3D[{pts2, pts1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Brown, Blue}]
```

[image]

It is natural to ask whether `region1` actually stops where shown here.  It does not.  For instance,

```
NMaximize[z, {x, y, z} ∈ region1]
(* {10., {x -> -10.7241, y -> 2.59226, z -> 10.}} *)
```

That the fault lies with `RandomPoint` also can be seen from

```
Max[Cases[pts1, {_, _, z_} -> z]]
(* 7.67556 *)
```

**Workaround**

One way to recover the missing upper portion of the `region1` plot is

```
region3 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 <= x - y + 2*z <= 7, 
    {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, 7, 10}}];
pts3 = RandomPoint[region3, 1.5 10^3];
ListPointPlot3D[{pts2, pts1, pts3}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Brown, Blue, Red}]
```

[image]

A similar workaround could be used to recover the small portion of `region1` missing at the bottom of the plot.

It is natural to ask why the lower bound in `z` in `region3` is not set at `7.67556`, so that there is no overlap between `region1` and `region3`.  It turns out that `RandomPoint` generates no points below about `z = 8` in that case.  To eliminate the overlapping region of points, one could use `DeleteCases`.

`ListPointPlot3D` also seems to behave strangely, effectively ignoring `PlotRange`.  So, for instance,

```
plt3 = ListPointPlot3D[pts3, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -10, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
Options[plt3, PlotRange]
(* {PlotRange -> {{-15.7075, 6.41088}, {-7.15594, 15.7007}, Automatic}} *)
```

I leave it to others to decide whether this is a bug in `ListPointPlot3D`.  Certainly the treatment of `PlotRange` differs from that in `ListPlot`.

For the record,

```
$Version
(* "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is an issue, thanks for looking into this @bbgodfrey. I went ahead and created four regions and got rid of the upper/lower z-bounds by increasing to `-20<=z<=20`. `region1` is what I want, `region2` through `region4` are for testing.

> `region1` is the original region that I want bounded by `equation1`, `x`, `y`, and two planes `6<=x-y+2*z<=7` (blue)
>
> `region2` is the solid region bounded by `x`, `y`, and two planes `6<=x-y+2*z<=7` (brown)
>
> `region3` is just `region1` with `z<=0` (green).
>
> `region4` is just `region1` with `z>=0` (red).

```
(*Define equation1*) s = 0.36109; t = 1*(1 - s);
equation1 = 1.505 < (1 - s)*8*(Sin[2*x]*Sin[z]*Cos[y] + Sin[2*y]*Sin[x]*Cos[z] + Sin[2*z]*Sin[y]*Cos[x]) - s*4*(Cos[2*x]*Cos[2*y] + Cos[2*y]*Cos[2*z] + Cos[2*z]*Cos[2*x]) - t;

(*Define the regions*)
region1 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 < x - y + 2*z < 7, {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -20, 20}}];
region2 = ImplicitRegion[6 < x - y + 2*z < 7, {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -20, 20}}];
region3 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 < x - y + 2*z < 7, {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, -20, 0}}];
region4 = ImplicitRegion[equation1 && 6 < x - y + 2*z < 7, {{x, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {y, -5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {z, 0, 20}}];

(*Now I make random points inside of these regions, the total number of points "pt" is left as a variable so we can change it later*)
pts1[pt_] := RandomPoint[region1, pt];
pts2[pt_] := RandomPoint[region2, pt];
pts3[pt_] := RandomPoint[region3, pt/2];
pts4[pt_] := RandomPoint[region4, pt/2];
```

Now to check how `RandomPoint` distributed the points I check first the regions:

```
RegionPlot3D[{region1, region2, region3, region4}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 500, PlotRange -> {{-5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {-5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {-20, 20}}, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0.25], Blue}, {Opacity[0.25], Brown}, {Opacity[0.25], Red}, {Opacity[0.25], Green}}]
```

[image]

Everything looks ok as far as how the regions are defined.

Now let's check how the points generated by `RandomPoint` are distributed:

```
Table[ListPointPlot3D[{pts1[pt], pts2[pt], pts3[pt], pts4[pt]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {-5*Pi, 5*Pi}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[1], Blue}, {Opacity[1], Brown}, {Opacity[1], Red}, {Opacity[1], Green}}], {pt, {10, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5}}]
```

[image]

It seems that there is indeed a bug with the way `RandomPoint` calculates the region in which to distribute points, like @bbgodfrey suggests. As you can see, `region1` (blue) is decent but does not generate points near the minimum `z`. `region2` (brown) generates points in the entire region as defined. `region3` (red) and `region4` (green) are most problematic.

For now `Randompoint[region1, 10^4]` is good enough. I have contacted Mathematica tech support and will update if their comments are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the random points being generated will serve as coordinate centers for randomly oriented molecules.

We can generate the molecules onto the random points in `region1`. We want each molecule to have a random orientation so we need to do rotational transformations before we translate the molecule to its new point

```
teosPEO := Table[
   GeometricTransformation[
    GeometricTransformation[
     GeometricTransformation[
      GeometricTransformation[
       GeometricTransformation[
        First@ChemicalData["TetraethylOrthosilicate", "MoleculePlot"],
        ScalingMatrix[{2*10^-3, 2*10^-3, 2*10^-3}]
        ],(*The first transform is to scale the molecule*)
       RotationTransform[RandomReal[2*Pi], {1, 0, 0}]
       ],(*The second transform is to rotate the molecule by a random angle about the x-axis*)
      RotationTransform[RandomReal[2*Pi], {0, 1, 0}]
      ],(*The third transform is to rotate the molecule by a random angle about the y-axis*)
     RotationTransform[RandomReal[2*Pi], {0, 0, 1}]
     ],(*The fourth transform is to rotate the molecule by a random angle about the z-axis*)
    TranslationTransform[{pts1[[i, 1]], pts1[[i, 2]], pts1[[i, 3]]}]
    ],(*The fifth transform is to translate the molecule by a random {x,y,z} vector that we defined by the RandomPoint function above*)
   {i, pt}];
```

[image]

You can see that there is a missing portion near the minimum in `z`. Pretty decent though.