# Using LatticeData to fill a space with spheres in a face-centered cubic (fcc) lattice packing arrangement

Tags: curated-data, geometry, lattices

I have a large sphere of radius $R_1$ which I would like to pack with $N$ smaller radius of radius $r_2<R_1$ arranged in a face-centered cubic (fcc) packing arrangement (i.e. Kepler's optimal sphere packing geometry).  Is there a way for me to use Mathematica's built-in LatticeData functionality to accomplish this, perhaps with an after-the-fact pruning step?  Can I do this for the other lattice types Mathematica has data for?

Comment: Related: [Can a LatticeData image be displayed in a space filled fashion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18789/245)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
basis = LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Basis"];
points = Tuples[Range[-4, 4], 3].basis;
inside = Select[points, Norm[#] <= 4 &];
Graphics3D[Sphere[inside, 0.25]]
```

[image]

For more complex polyhedra see: [Checking if a point is in a convex 3D polyhedron](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15195/checking-if-a-point-is-in-a-convex-3d-polyhedron)