# Is there any faster implementation of DominantColors?

Tags: image-processing, color, generative-art

The function DominantColors is a simple function but runs incredibly slow when the number n of dominant colors to find is large - it is currently the biggest bottleneck in my code:

```
tst = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
gr = ListDensityPlot[SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[{}, {4000, 3}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> False, Mesh -> All, 
  ImageSize -> 475]
polys = Cases[Normal@gr, _Polygon, \[Infinity]];
vpolys = Polygon[#[[1]], VertexTextureCoordinates -> #[[1]]] & /@ 
   polys;
pieces = Table[Graphics[{Texture[tst], p}], {p, vpolys}];
colors = Table[
   RandomChoice[DominantColors[p, 5][[2 ;;]]], {p, pieces}];
cpolys = Map[{#[[2]], Polygon[#[[1, 1]]]} &, Thread@{polys, colors}];
gcp = Graphics[cpolys]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Has anyone any ideas to reimplement it to be faster?

**Motivation & Clarification**

I use mathematica to do explorative art. I'm using this subroutine `DominantColors` as a tool in my various software art projects for example:
[image]
I don't need someone to implement a specific image effect, rather I need a faster dominant-n-colors-finder. I'm thinking of using cudalink...

Comment: Show your slow code, please.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure, I'll post the code I have for context, but I have zero code for the topic of the question - I don't know where to start on the actual reimplementation here.

Comment: Off to the races everyone!

Comment: I wonder how much of that slowdown is due to Mathematica trying to convert the simple input into `Entity["Lena", Entity["ImageData", {{Entity["Color", {Entity["Red", Quantity[...]}], ...}, ...}]]` and choking on its own vomit :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `domCol` below is about 100 times faster than `DominantColors`.

Basic plan: Create enough color bins throughout the color space occupied by the image; count the number of pixels in each bin; return the sorted colors.  The function works in the LAB color space so we can use `EuclideanDistance` for the distance between colors.  The centers of the bins are jiggled by a random offset each call, so that the return value is not deterministic.  The option `"RandomSeed"` can be used to give a reproducible result.

*Examples:*

```
domCol[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
domCol[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems to find similar colors to the ones found by `DominantColors`, although in a different order here and there.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Code:*

Suppose `DominantColors` spends some time fiddling with constructing an optimal set of color bins, which seems a reasonable hypothesis.  This approach does not, but uses a simple heuristic to get a binning that's likely to do a pretty good job.  That seems the probable reason for the difference in performance.  The function `domCol` uses a face-center cubic close-packing of spheres, with slightly larger spheres that overlap a little (radius `0.55 dx` where `dx` is the diameter determined by the heuristic).  Some of the space is not covered.  (Technically, they're not really bins.)  The distance can be set explicitly by the option `MinColorDistance`, which in this case will actually determine the exact color distance between adjacent bins, but the option exists already (for `DominantColors`).  One could make the `0.55` fudge factor an option, too, for more control.  With this approach `Nearest` is a convenient and efficient way to do the bin counts.

```
ClearAll[domCol];
Options[domCol] = {"RandomSeed" -> Automatic, MinColorDistance -> Automatic};
domCol[img_, n_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{idata, nf, bounds, basis, points, colorbins, intensity},
  idata = Flatten[ImageData@ColorConvert[img, "LAB"], 1];
  nf = Nearest@idata;
  bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose@idata;
  With[{dx = 
     OptionValue[MinColorDistance] /.
      Automatic -> (Times @@ Flatten[Differences /@ bounds]/n)^(1/3)/4},
   basis = LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Basis"];
   If[IntegerQ@OptionValue["RandomSeed"] || 
      StringQ@OptionValue["RandomSeed"],
    SeedRandom[OptionValue["RandomSeed"]]
    ];
   points = Tuples[Range[# - dx + RandomReal[{-dx, dx}/2], #2 + dx, dx] & @@@
      (Sort /@ (Inverse@Transpose[basis].bounds))].basis;
   colorbins = Select[points, Length@nf[#, {1, dx}] >= 1 &];
   intensity = Length@nf[#, {All, 0.55 dx}] & /@ colorbins
   ];
  LABColor /@ colorbins[[Ordering[intensity, -Min[n, Length@colorbins]]]] // Reverse
  ]
```

The use of the `"FaceCenteredCubic"` lattice is based in part on this answer by [s0rce](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/65/s0rce): [Using LatticeData to fill a space with spheres in a face-centered cubic (fcc) lattice packing arrangement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/using-latticedata-to-fill-a-space-with-spheres-in-a-face-centered-cubic-fcc-la/26036#26036)

Answer (score 7):

Use of `ColorQuantize` Much faster. Not exactly the same, but close and for an art project is OK I think.

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

QuaCol[i_, n_] := RGBColor /@ Union[Flatten[ImageData[ColorQuantize[i, n]], 1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

#### The problem is not with `DominantColors`

Try varying the number of colours selected by running this snippet.  I vary the number of selected colours from 1 to 10, and measure the time to calculate `DominantColours` ten times:

```
Table[
  First@AbsoluteTiming@
     Table[DominantColors[p, i], {p, RandomChoice[pieces, 10]}]
 , {i, 10}]

(* {6.544491, 7.658153, 6.025185, 7.401227, 6.483151,
    9.054305, 8.664255, 11.058545, 13.238622, 13.285135} *)
```

Empirically, the time increases linearly with the number of colours, but the constant overhead is very high --- basically *the time your code requires has almost nothing to do with the number of colours selected*.

The problem seems to be that each element of `pieces` is a complex image - it contains the whole *Lena* image for starters.  Each element of `pieces` is 780 kB in size and - not knowing about how it works - it's unsurprising to me that it takes some time to compute.

If you try this with a bigger image than *Lena* you'll just run into more problems--- especially if you try to generate more than 4000 pieces because you're manipulating a bigger image.  The solution is to not to fix `DominantColors` but to come up with a colour selection routine that isn't so memory intensive.  If you rewrite the question with that in mind, I think a good answer could be found.

Comment: I suspect you can avoid `DominantColors` altogether by sampling just the color of the center of each "piece."  For large number of pieces (Voronoi cells) that color will suffice.

Comment: I agree.  The question has little to do with `DominantColors`.  The problem is the basic algorithm which makes too many copies of the image--- it presumably can't be adapted to bigger images, as the complexity is at least proportional to the size of the basic image (Lena is small) and the number of pieces; and it already takes 3.5 GB RAM.