# Specifying the number of DominantColors to be extracted from an image

Tags: image-processing, color

How does one get a certain number of `DominantColors` and is it always possible to do so?  I have tried specifying the number as well as the option `ColorCoverage -> 0`.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raN1w.jpg):

[image: example of DominantColors output]

More examples: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FDUY.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrkZi.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKKMp.jpg)

Comment: `DominantColors[img, no. of colors]`. Your problem may not be so trivial. In that case give an example where you think it is not working.

Comment: @Sumit, I added an example.

Comment: It's not possible using just options, it may return fewer than the requested number of colors.

Comment: maybe request a few more than you need and take the top n. `DominantColors[img,8, {"Color", "Count"}]`  It would be better if your uploaded example was just the image, not a screenshot with the white around it..BTW.

Comment: FWIW I can not reproduce any case where `DominantColors` returns less than the requested number. (unless starting with an image with fewer discrete colors) @E.Alderson what version do you have? Can you see if you have this issue with some standard example, eg `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Splash"}]`

Comment: @george2079, Mathematica 11.0.1. The issue mostly occurs when working with monochromatic images (I added more examples). It works fine on Example Data.

Comment: no issues with the new examples either ( v10.1 ).  Even If I make a truely monochromatic image `img=ImageMultiply[ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Splash"}], "Grayscale"], Red]
` it works fine.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79885)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work in every case I've tried (v. 10.4, Mac).

ColorQuantize *forces* the number of colors in the image.  Here's a screenshot of the original:

[image]

Here's the quantized image:

```
quantizedImage = ColorQuantize[img, 5]
```

[image]

My code worked fine on the screen shot of the poser's image, though admittedly the colors are rather dark.

Here are the extracted colors:

```
DominantColors[quantizedImage, 5]

{RGBColor[0.242519, 0.347167, 0.144226], 
 RGBColor[0.233793, 0.319928, 0.134609], 
 RGBColor[0.357113, 0.483923, 0.216957], 
 RGBColor[0.340756, 0.432562, 0.162432], 
 RGBColor[0.16798, 0.278479, 0.11706]}
```

or

```
Graphics[
 Table[{SortBy[DominantColors[quantizedImage, 5],Mean][[i]], 
        Disk[{2 i, 0}]}, 
      {i, 5}]]
```

[image]

I believe the dark colors arise because most of the image *is* quite dark, and the light highlights, while centered, represent a very small portion of the total image.

Comment: I tried to grab the OP's image, had to do a screencapture for it, but [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUoNN.png).  But I couldn't get it to work with your code

Comment: @user9490, didn't work for me too, I got only two colors.

Comment: This does give the five colors from the quantized image, they are a bit darker than the dominant colors found by the built-in function:  `RGBColor@*Most /@ Union[Flatten[ImageData[quantizedImage], 1]]`

Comment: I have been using this function for color extraction, even though it does not produce the desired output:`color[img_] := 
 MapAt[RGBColor, 
  Tally[Flatten[ImageData[ColorQuantize[ImageResize[img, 50], 5]], 
    1]], {All, 1}]
col[img_] := First[#] & /@ color[img];`

Comment: @David didn't work for me either