# Creating 2d-HexagonalLattice and 3d-HexagonalClosePacking lattice with LatticeData function

Tags: geometry, curated-data, lattices

I found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/using-latticedata-to-fill-a-space-with-spheres-in-a-face-centered-cubic-fcc-la) a solution by s0rce on how one can for example create a 3d `FaceCenteredCubic` lattice structure:

```
basis = LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Basis"];
points = Tuples[Range[-4, 4], 3].basis;
inside = Select[points, Norm[#] <= 4 &];
Graphics3D[Sphere[inside, 0.25]]
```

**How can I build up a 2d lattice of `HexagonalLattice` structure and a 3d lattice  of `HexagonalClosePacking` by using `LatticeData` and find the corresponding coordinates?**

I tried the following:

1.

```
LatticeData[]

{"BaseCenteredMonoclinic", "BaseCenteredOrthorhombic", \
"BodyCenteredCubic", "BodyCenteredOrthorhombic", \
"CenteredTetragonal", "CoxeterTodd", "FaceCenteredCubic", \
"FaceCenteredOrthorhombic", "HexagonalClosePacking", \
"HexagonalLattice", "KorkineZolotarev", "Leech", "SimpleCubic", \
"SimpleHexagonal", "SimpleMonoclinic", "SimpleOrthorhombic", \
"SimpleTetragonal", "SimpleTriclinic", "SimpleTrigonal", \
"SquareLattice", "TetrahedralPacking"}

LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", "Properties"]

{"AlternateNames", "AutomorphismGroupOrder", "Basis", \
"CenterDensity", "Classes", "CoveringRadius", "CoxeterNumber", \
"Density", "Determinant", "Dimension", "Dual", "Even", "Extremal", \
"GeneratorMatrix", "Genus", "GlueVectors", "GramMatrix", \
"HermiteInvariant", "Image", "Integral", "KissingNumber", \
"MinimalNorm", "MinimalVectors", "ModularNumber", "Name", \
"Nonextremal", "Nonintegral", "Nonunimodular", "Notation", "Odd", \
"PackingRadius", "QuadraticForm", "RadialFunction", "StandardName", \
"ThetaSeriesFunction", "Thickness", "Unimodular", "Volume"}

LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", "Basis"]

Missing["NotApplicable"]
```

Here I probably need the `MinimalVectors` to produce the crystal structure, but how?

2.

```
LatticeData["HexagonalLattice", "Basis"]

SparseArray[Automatic, {2, 2}, 0, {
 1, {{0, 2, 3}, {{2}, {1}, {2}}}, {1, -1, -1}}]
```

How can I get the coordinates from the `SparseArray`?

**Summary:**

1.

```
list1 = LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", "Properties"]

Grid[{#, LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", #]} & /@ list1, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

2.

```
list2 = LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", "Properties"]

Grid[{#, LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", #]} & /@ list2, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61834/how-to-create-an-hexagonal-lattice-structure/61877

Comment: @Alrubaie: Thank you. I would like to see a solution with `LatticeData`.

Comment: What do you try and with what results? You already know about `LatticeData[]`. Why did you fail to get good results?

Comment: @ Somos: See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to [MSE question 3100098](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3100098) "Calculate cartesian coordinates from lattice points in hexagonal closest packing (HCP)" may be what you need.

> Try $\,\textrm{HCP}(i,j,k) =
>  (i+(j+m)/2,\, (3j+m)/\sqrt{12},\, k\sqrt{2/3})\,$ where $\,m=\textrm{mod}(k,2)\,$ and $\,i,j,k\,$ are any integers.
>   Check this with the [OEIS sequence A004012](https://oeis.org/A004012) "Theta series of hexagonal close-packing.". What the formula expresses with the use of $\,m\,$ the parity of $\,k\,$ is that HCP is **not** a lattice but the union of two lattices. The first is centered at the origin and the second is a shifted copy of the first.

However, `LatticeData[]` has much information about HCP missing so you need some other source of information about it. The `MinimalVectors` is not sufficient by itself. In the case of `HexagonalLattice` you can use:

```
LatticeData["HexagonalLattice", "Basis"] // Normal
```

which returns the result `{{-1, 1}, {0, -1}}`. The documentation of `LatticeData[]` has a section on **Possible Issues** and the first example advises to use `Normal[]` to get a matrix. However, since "HexagonalLattice" **is** a lattice, the result seems obscure. It should be something like

```
{{1, 0}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}
```

instead which **does** generate the lattice. This lattice is also known as the $A2$ lattice of [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer).