# 3D Cylinder with uniform distribution in volume

Tags: graphics3d, random, chemistry

I would like to draw a figure in 3D where I have a cylinder (or ellipsoid) and some spheres in volume with fixed distenced between.
I understand how to build a cylinder or Random spheres in cube, but how can I match two algorithms together?

My task is modelling particle (or agglomerate) with some voids(spheres), also i have all dimensions.

I am looking for suggestion on how to proceed.
Thank you!

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26031/using-latticedata-to-fill-a-space-with-spheres-in-a-face-centered-cubic-fcc-la

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly: you want a cylinder with spherical holes within it, all separated by a minimum distance? Are these spheres all the same size?

Comment: J. M.'s slightly less busy, yes. There are some range of spheres(holes), for example 3-6 nm. Thus spheres are statical in the volume with the fixed distance.