# Cropping a non-cubic lattice unit cell

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, lattices

I would like to crop the hexagonal close-packed system as a hexagon and not as a cube.  I would like to use the following `volumetricPlot` already given on this exchange by [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens).

```
volumetricPlot[latticeType_] := Module[
  {
   img = LatticeData[latticeType, "Image"],
   r = LatticeData[latticeType, "PackingRadius"]
   },
  Show[
   img /. Sphere[pt_, r_] :> {},
   Map[
    RegionPlot3D[(EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, #] < r),
      {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
      Mesh -> False,
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]
      ] &, Cases[img, Sphere[pos_, _] :> pos, Infinity]]
   ]
  ]

  volumetricPlot["HexagonalClosePacking"]
```

However as a newbie to *Mathematica* I am not sure how to change `RegionPlot3D` to crop at the hexagon boundaries.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

The earlier answer that the question refers to is here: [Can a LatticeData image be displayed in a space filled fashion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18793/245).

**Edit: a much faster approach is shown at the end**

Generalizing the `RegionPlot3D` approach to a non-cubic lattice is certainly possible, but it doesn't look as nice because there are always artifacts due to the finite resolution near corners of the constrained surfaces. Here is what it looks like, with a large `PlotPoints` setting for `RegionPlot3D` - so it's also quite slow to render.

To speed things up I rearranged the `RegionPlot3D` so that it is called once for each sphere with its *individual* plot range set to be a small box of side `2r` around it; and the results are then combined in `Show`. This is just a small modification of my earlier answer (linked above).

The main new thing is that I get the hexagonal region by calling `PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 6}, "RegionFunction"]`. This way I don't need to write a lot of inequalities to define the borders:

```
volumetricPlot[latticeType_] := Module[
  {pos,
   img = LatticeData[latticeType, "Image"],
   r = LatticeData[latticeType, "PackingRadius"]},
  Show[img /. Sphere[pt_, r_] :> {},
   Map[
    RegionPlot3D[
      (
       EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, #] < r && 
        PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 6}, "RegionFunction"][x, y, 0]),
      {x, #[[1]] - r, #[[1]] + r}, {y, #[[2]] - r, #[[2]] + 
        r}, {z, #[[3]] - r, #[[3]] + r},
      PlotPoints -> 30,
      Mesh -> False,
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]] &,
    Cases[img, Sphere[pos_, _] :> pos, Infinity]],
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
  ]

volumetricPlot["HexagonalClosePacking"]
```

[image: hexagon]

You can see how the hexagonal faces cut off the spheres as desired, but on the other hand the limitations of `RegionPlot3D` make the edges appear jagged. Nevertheless, the question was about how to modify the `RegionPlot3D` approach, so this is one way to do it.

And of course, the bug I mentioned in the earlier answer still remains: the spheres should be touching but are not doing that at the bottom.

**Replacing `RegionPlot3d` to get sharper cutoff**

Since the `RegionPlot3D` wrinkles can't really be removed with any sensible amount of processing time, I would suggest going back to a less "solid" looking approach which however renders the edges much more cleanly. It is based on `ContourPlot3D` to draw the spheres:

```
volumetricPlot[latticeType_] := 
 Module[{img = LatticeData[latticeType, "Image"], 
   r = LatticeData[latticeType, "PackingRadius"]}, 
  Show[img /. Sphere[pt_, r_] :> {},
   Map[ContourPlot3D[
      (#.#) &[{x, y, z} - #] == r^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 
       1},
      Mesh -> False,
      ContourStyle -> Opacity[.5],
      RegionFunction -> (PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 6}, 
           "RegionFunction"][#1, #2, 0] &)] &, 
    Cases[img, Sphere[pos_, _] :> pos, Infinity]]]]

volumetricPlot["HexagonalClosePacking"]
```

[image: hexagon 3]

Here you could further improve the smoothness by adding `PlotPoints` - the output shown above is for the standard settings, to illustrate that it already works quite well - and *really fast* by comparison.

Comment: Thank-you!!! This is great. At the moment I am fine with the rough edges and I did see your earlier comment about the incorrect Image part of LatticeData.